# What pattern error is occurring in preg_match_all?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a piece of code (which I did not write) where a error is given when trying to call the pre_match_all function:

```
$pattern = "/([\w-:\*]*)(?:\#([\w-]+)|\.([\w-]+))?(?:\[@?(!?[\w-:]+)(?:([!*^$]?=)[\"']?(.*?)[\"']?)?\])?([\/, ]+)/is";
    preg_match_all($pattern, trim($selector_string).' ', $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

As I'm not a novice programmer I really don't have any clue where to start, I tried some online checkers but I can't quite find the error/typo in the pattern.

Comment: It would help if you include the error you're getting, the string you're trying to match and the result (if any is available). Also, what are you trying to do? maybe there is no need to regex

Comment: The hyphens in the character class should be at the start or at the end, or you should escape them `$pattern = "/([\w:\*-]*)(?:\#([\w-]+)|\.([\w-]+))?(?:\[@?(!?[\w:-]+)(?:([!*^$]?=)[\"']?(.*?)[\"']?)?\])?([\/, ]+)/is";`